# search a pattern from a file with a combination of defined variable and extra strings using powershell

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a text file as mentioned below:

```
    04Jul@15:08 ERROR: The Ticket and Load data do not match: NUM[MXS035] 
    04Jul@15:14 No data for MXS035
    04Jul@15:14 Ticket = [MXS035]
    04Jul@15:39 Ticket = [ABC077]
    04Jul@16:14 gNoRcomp = [72]
    04Jul@16:14 Test lines 12345
    04Jul@16:14 gNoRcomp = [72]
    04Jul@16:14 test file content not displayed
    MU: module rpt3.cpp, line 8652
    Database 0
    Communications 0
```

I have created a $date value which captures the common part of the text file 04Jul for a prticular date using the variable

```
    $date_value=Get-date -Format ddMMM
```

when displayed the valye of $date_value we get 04Jul
I need to search a pattern which is in the text file which is having the date as common and the workdings ticket as common..the rest of the values in the line change.

example :

I need to capture the lines below:

```
    04Jul@15:14 Ticket = [MXS035]
    04Jul@15:39 Ticket = [ABC077]
```

This has 04Jul which is already captured in a variable $date_value@ and the time filed changes and " Ticket = [" is again common and next 6 characters change and the last ] is common which do not change.

So the requirement is

```
    $date_value@......Ticket=[......]
```

the above mentioned part is common in the text file line which needs to be captured.

I tried the below select string and is not working.

```
    select-string -pattern "$date_value@\d+:\d+ Ticket = [[]ABCDEF[]]" test.txt
```

Any suggestions plesase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend the part of the regex where you are looking for a reference in square brackets.

If you want to look for characters that have special meaning in regular expression syntax, you must escape them using the backslash character first e.g. to escape an opening square bracket, it's \[ (in fact to type this, I had to escape the backslash itself by typing it twice)

The following works:

```
select-string -pattern "$date_value@\d+:\d+ Ticket = \[[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}\]" test.txt
```

So, it was all fine up until the reference in square brackets. What I've done here tells it to look for an opening square bracket, followed by 3 letters of either upper or lower case, followed by 3 digits, and finally a closing square bracket.

In my test, with a file using the contents you provided, I got back the following results:

```
test.txt:3:04Jul@15:14 Ticket = [MXS035]
test.txt:4:04Jul@15:39 Ticket = [ABC077]
```

...which tells you filename, line number that matched, and the line contents.

For further help, in the Powershell command window or ISE GUI, enter: **help about_regular_expressions**

Answer (score 1):

this is example of regex for string like this: "04Jul@15:14 Ticket = [MXS035]"

```
"04Jul@15:14 Ticket = [MXS035]" -Match "(\d{2}\w{3})@(\d{2}:\d{2})\sTicket\s=\s\[(\w*)\]"
$date = ($Matches[1] | Get-date -Format ddMMM)
$time = $Matches[2]
$ticket = $Matches[3]
$date, $time, $ticket
```

this code will select all strings that matches to pattern

```
Select-String -Pattern "(\d{2}\w{3})@(\d{2}:\d{2})\sTicket\s=\s\[(\w*)\]" test.txt
```

with variable date

```
$date_value='04Jul'
Select-String -Pattern $date_value+"@\d{2}:\d{2}\sTicket\s=\s\[\w*\]" "C:\test.txt"
```

Comment: sorry,i couldnt get your answer.
Could you please help me with the command that needs to be used so that i can try and check ?

Comment: first of all copy this command to powershell tool that you are using and run it

Comment: if you only need to find strings that matches to pattern - just use correct pattern in select-string command:Select-String -Pattern "(\d{2}\w{3})@(\d{2}:\d{2})\sTicket\s=\s\[(\w*)\]" test.txt

Comment: i am worried about the select-string command which is not present in the above code which you have given and also more confusing thing is that the date and time in the line which was used is changing in my text file everyday and everytime..so the first match line is not constant always.Any suggestions pelase

Comment: but if you want to place values of date and ticket number into variables for some reasons - then you can use -Match command and $Matches object for it

Comment: In the command line you gave Select-String -Pattern "(\d{2}\w{3})@(\d{2}:\d{2})\sTicket\s=\s[(\w*)]" my $date_value variable is not used.If that is not used i am suspecting all the lines for different dates are also fetched by the command line.

Comment: this pattern is for date: (\d{2}\w{3}) in another strings there are no word 'Ticket = ' - so dont worry - just try

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding about date )) - i have added new code

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern, change `[[]ABCDEF[]]` to `\[[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}\]` to match a ticket number consisting of 3 uppercase letters followed by 3 digits between literal square brackets:

```
$date_value = Get-date -Format ddMMM
Select-String "$date_value@\d+:\d+ Ticket = \[[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}\]" test.txt
```

This gives me the following output when I use it on a file `test.txt` with the sample content from your question:

```
test.txt:3:04Jul@15:14 Ticket = [MXS035]
test.txt:4:04Jul@15:39 Ticket = [ABC077]
```

Comment: When i have tried to execute the above,i am not getting any output on the screen,cursor goes to to the next line for new commnad.

PS D:\Temp\Arun> select-string -pattern "$date_value@\d+:\d+ Ticket = \[[A-Z]{3}
[0-9]{3}\]" test.txt
PS D:\Temp\Arun>

Comment: You didn't escape the outer square brackets. Compare your expression to the one in my answer.